# How to sample records uniformly in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

What is the best way for sampling records in Solr?

Say I have a query that returns  1000000 records and I'd like to take 10 samples from these uniformly. What is the most appropriate way for doing this in a Solr query?

Answer (score 2):

Implement [a `random` field in Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html), sort by this field by using a dynamic field with a random name, and then limit the search result to return ten documents. The same index version and the same field name will give the same result, so you can also do pagination and exploration on the dataset if needed.

```
<types>
  ...
  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
  ... 
 </types>
 <fields>
  ...
  <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  ...
 </fields>
```

You then sort by this field with a random name, such as `sort=random_12345678` and limit the number of documents with `rows=10`.

Answer (score 0):

Faceting would help you in this case.

Faceting is the arrangement of search results into categories based on indexed terms. Searchers are presented with the indexed terms, along with numerical counts of how many matching documents were found were each term. Faceting makes it easy for users to explore search results, narrowing in on exactly the results they are looking for.

To learn more on  faceting in solr query do read the following link.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting

Comment: faceting won't give you sampling in a single query. You will have to first get a list of facet value counts, then make independent requests to sample over them.

Answer (score 0):

In Solr with support of Streaming Expressions, you can random sample in a collection, using https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/stream-source-reference.html#random However, you will still need random field indexed.